# Create a link while typing using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

So, while typing into a input form field, I would like to show a hyperlink below (that is updated while writing)

E.g., I'd be typing

**"This is my name"**

this should be created below the field as a link while I am typing:

*http://www.example.com/index.php?name=This+is+my+Name*

How would I approach this?

Comment: I'm sorry Tobias, but you've been a member for more than a year... You know this is not a *code-for-me* site

Comment: Look at jQuery `change()` and Javascript `encodeURIComponent()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do not want to make it your habit to take SO as a code for me site but this time here it is for you:

```
var field = document.getElementById("field");
var link = document.getElementById("link");
field.onchange = function() {
    link.href = "http://www.example.com/?q=" + encodeURIComponent(field.value);
    console.log(link.href);
};
```

Notice I did not code it for you in jQuery, I would like you to change it for yourself, if you want to.

Comment: Why is it downvoted anyway?

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I dont see where in my question I wrote that I needed a complete solution, I would have been already happy to be pointed into a direction like @Basic (thank you too!) did it, since I didnt know how to "google" it, or how to approach it and also didnt find anything on SO searching it. So again thanks to you, in any case.

Comment: Probably because you just wrote a solution for him in a way that didn't require him to learn anything—which isn't really in the spirit of this community. I'd never downvote for functional code, but y'know..

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Dont let them discourage you to help people, I did learn a lot from this as I am a total javascript noob... I've been on this now since 5 hours, trying to understand more... and I can **guarantee** you this wouldnt have happened without your answer. To those others: Downvote my comment as you like, you're the majority, clearly you "must be right."